# Windows 7 64 bit enterprise lock sceen without password field

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, display

I lock my notebook and the lock screen will be sometimes without password field, so I cannot enter anymore. It looks like there would not be usericon and textfield and button there. Have you ever seen such? Any recommendation? I use HP 3010sg notebook and i installed digital persona software that could affect the locking screen. Any suggestions are welcome. This time I can do only stopping computer and starting again. After simple sleeping or hibernate it remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most probably a bug caused by the Digital Persona Software that you installed.

Make sure that it is compatible with your version of Windows, and specifically that you've downloaded the correct 64-bit version.

Comment: after uninstalling digital persona it is not coming anymore. However i miss fingerprint reader a bit.

Comment: Check for updated versions or possible 3rd party alternatives that support your fingerprint reader.